# Does docker use virtualization solution when running in linux machines?

Tags: docker, virtualization

When using Docker for Windows, the containers run side-by-side in a hyper-v linux VM on Windows. 
So when launching a container in ubuntu, is any virtualization solution like hyper-v needed or are the containers just running as processes inside ubuntu?

**Source for my first statement -** [How docker desktop runs linux containers on Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264920/how-docker-desktop-runs-linux-containers-on-windows-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, why hyper-v?**

The reason for docker on windows using hyper-v VM just because: for a linux container, it had to share the linux kernel of host. But on windows, we do not have linux kernel, so docker set a hyper-v VM for you, then let your container to share the kernel.

**Second, why not VM on linux?**

But on linux, the host already has a linux kernel, so container can share this kernel without using any VM.

In fact, from next diagram you can see when you start a new container, it will auto new a process `containerd-shim`, it will run as a process which you can use `ps aux | grep docker` to see it on linux host.

[image]

**And, finally, what is container?**

Docker uses a technology called namespaces to provide the isolated workspace called the container. When you run a container, Docker creates a set of namespaces for that container, then every process in container will run in a separated namespace. See [official docementation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#namespaces).

Answer (score 1):

"Containers" is a concept that combines (primarily) two features implemented in the Linux kernel - [control groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) and [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces). You need the VM on top of Windows because Windows does not implement these two features.

Therefore, when you run containers *natively* on Linux, each container will simply run as separate processes constrained by control groups and namespaces.